# How to access result hash from Geocoder serach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, google-geocoder

When I run the query

```
Geocoder.search(@data.zip_code).inspect
```

the output is following hash:

```
[#<Geocoder::Result::Google:0x007fc46360e8f0 @data={"address_components"=>[{"long_name"=>"92301",
"short_name"=>"92301", "types"=>["postal_code"]},
{"long_name"=>"Adelanto", "short_name"=>"Adelanto",
"types"=>["locality", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"California",
"short_name"=>"CA", "types"=>["administrative_area_level_1",
"political"]}, {"long_name"=>"United States", "short_name"=>"US",
"types"=>["country", "political"]}], "formatted_address"=>"Adelanto,
CA 92301, USA",
"geometry"=>{"bounds"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>34.82148189999999,
"lng"=>-117.35638}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>34.506587,
"lng"=>-117.69486}}, "location"=>{"lat"=>34.6599838,
"lng"=>-117.5026174}, "location_type"=>"APPROXIMATE",
"viewport"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>34.82148189999999,
"lng"=>-117.35638}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>34.506587,
"lng"=>-117.69486}}}, "types"=>["postal_code"]}, @cache_hit=nil>]
```

I am trying to access these information (for example the field `formatted_address`), but I don't know how to obtain these data.

In the documentation is written:

```
Every Geocoder::Result object, result, provides the following data:
  result.latitude - float
  result.longitude - float
  result.coordinates - array of the above two
  ...
```

However, this doesn't work here (not sure if I am doing something wrong or these information are outdated).

However, how can I obtain from the hash the whole address?

**EDIT:**
Solution:

```
puts Geocoder.search(@listing.zip_code)[0].data["formatted_address"]
# => Adelanto, CA 92301, USA
```

However, when the **Geocoder** call will return an error, or doesn't find something or the connection will timeout, I get error.
How to avoid this? My goal is to obtain the address and post it to Twitter, but when I will receive an error from Geocoder, so instead of posting these data to Twitter I will obtain an error, which is not very user-friendly.

Is there any way to detect an error in this query?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give the link to the gem you are using? So that I can install

Comment: The **Geocoder** gem: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder. Thank you Arup for your effort. (but maybe I think is the problem that I don't know how to access fields from the hash above)

Comment: `puts Geocoder… rescue 'Error occured'`

Comment: What do you get when you do: `Geocoder.search(@data.zip_code).count`, `Geocoder.search(@data.zip_code).first`, `Geocoder.search(@data.zip_code).class`